# Powershell copy to %appdata% mozilla profile

Tags: powershell, firefox, cmd, copy, mozilla

I Have problem witch my powershell code:
I make script in command line (CMD) and this script is work but not work good in active directory
I will make script to copy file from server to %appdata% witch no name folder
firefox make random names to profiles directory example: sadadasasda.default or d4sfsx.default-release
I must copy file from server to profile directory but i dont know how catch the name of directory.
Thanks for help

```bsh
$UserLogo=$env:UserName

Copy-Item -Path \\server\... -Destination C:\Users\$UserLogo\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default
Copy-Item -Path \\server\... -Destination C:\Users\$UserLogo\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default-release
```

Comment: this >>> `Get-Content -LiteralPath "$env:APPDATA\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini"` <<< will give you the list of profiles. find the one that has `Default=1` to get the current default. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Use Get-ChildItem to get the content from Profiles folder then try to work with them

an Example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:APPDATA\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles" | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -match "\.default"} | % {
 # copy content to *.default-release folder
 if($_.Name -match "\.default-release$"){
    Copy-Item -Path \\server\... -Destination $_.FullName
 } else {
  # copy content to *.default folder
    Copy-Item -Path \\server\... -Destination $_.FullName
 }
}
```

Comment: With PowerShell 3.0+, `Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "$Env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles" -Filter '*.default-release'` and omit `Where-Object`.

Comment: Are you sure that you have permission to access those files?

Comment: Yes you can, I just tested to write-host the $_.FullName